# how to Add key value pair to tree structure object using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I need to add key value pair at the end of the tree like json object.

```
[{
    "name": "minpur",
    "children": [{
        "name": "ppp1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "feeder",
            "children": [{
                "name": "rmu16",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "invt16",
                    "children": [{
                        "aname": "inv 01"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Expected

```
[{
  "name": "minpur",
  "children": [{
    "name": "ppp1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "feeder",
      "children": [{
        "name": "rmu16",
        "children": [{
          "name": "invt16",
          "children": [{
            "aname": "inv 01",
            **
            "value": 300 **
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

tried recursive function as below

```
let traverse = function(jsonObj) {
  if (jsonObj !== null && typeof jsonObj == "object") {
    return Object.entries(jsonObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key != "aname") {
        traverse(value);
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `aname` key exists on the object, and add the property if it does. If it doesn't iterate the children with `Array.forEach()`, and calls traverse on the children.

```js
const traverse = (key, value) => obj => {
  const inner = obj => {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj.value = value
    else obj.children.forEach(inner)
  }
  
  return inner(obj)
}

const tree = [{"name":"minpur","children":[{"name":"ppp1","children":[{"name":"feeder","children":[{"name":"rmu16","children":[{"name":"invt16","children":[{"aname":"inv 01"}]}]}]}]}]}]

tree.forEach(traverse('aname', 300))

console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, how can we make value dynamic, i.e inside the loop and add the values dynamically

Comment: I've updated the function to accept and key to search, and a value to set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more functional solution where the original values are not changed.
The children are inspected and if there is no children, the passed keys are used to extend the current node.

```js
const obj = [{
  "name": "minpur",
  "children": [{
    "name": "ppp1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "feeder",
      "children": [{
        "name": "rmu16",
        "children": [{
          "name": "invt16",
          "children": [{
            "aname": "inv 01"
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]

function addToLeaf(append, node) {
  if (!node.children) {
    return {
      ...node,
      ...append
    }
  }
  return { 
    ...node,
    ...{ children: node.children.map(child => addToLeaf(append, child))}
  }
}

const result = obj.map((node) => addToLeaf({
  value: 300
}, node));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help. this doesn't work if the value field is a dynamic value which is inside the loop.

Comment: Why not? You could pass in a function generating the value into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `JS` utility library `lodash` it gives you many methods to handle such complex structures.

For this I would suggest `_.set` - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set

```js
const _u = _.noConflict(); 
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
_u.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object);
// => 4
 
_u.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object);
// => 5
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function which traverses arrays of objects and merges a found object (by specified `key name`) with a specified by you argument. `No lodash` needed:

```js
let data = [{ "name": "minpur", "children": [{ "name": "ppp1", "children": [{ "name": "feeder", "children": [{ "name": "rmu16", "children": [{ "name": "invt16", "children": [{ "aname": "inv 01" }] }] }] }] }] }]

let deepSetByKey = (a, k, setObj) =>
  a.forEach(o => k in o ? Object.assign(o, setObj) : 
   'children' in o ? deepSetByKey(o.children, k, setObj) : 0) && a

deepSetByKey(data, 'aname', { value: 300 }) // call the fn

console.log(data[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0])
```

The idea is to recursively traverse with [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) when you find the prop you are looking for in the current object.

Comment: i have one doubt , how can we make the value dynamic instead of static value = 300, can we have something like value=data[i] ?

Comment: What is `data[i]`? Can you update your question above so there is a clear requirement of what and how it should work? You can simply change the `setObj` to whatever you want as it is now.